# Jalapeño Multipool Setup on OS X

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, mac

I have an ASIC Jalapeño Bitcoin Miner. It mines consistently at around 5000 GH/s. I have been mining using the BitMinter Miner and BitMinter Pool just because it is easy to setup and get running quickly and that's what I wanted to do upon receiving my Jalapeño. However, I now wish to maximize my mining profits. I have read lots about mining etc and I have seen a lot about multi mining. I found a pool called MultiPool and made an account. However, I am unsure how to get mining on the pool now. I have an iMac that I will be running the Jalapeño from. I want a simple, stable, and reliable mining program. But all my attempts to download CGMiner for Mac have failed. How can I get mining on Multipool with my Jalapeño?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MacMiner](http://fabulouspanda.co.uk/macminer/)

either use the fpga/asic or bfgminer window (which both use bfgminer) or the cgminer window depending on your driver setup. on 10.9 bfgminer should work without driver meddling and prior to 10.9 cgminer should work without installing drivers. You can run either from the command line or through MacMiner.

Answer (score 1):

Bfgminer is better than Cgminer. This it the right resource to check for update of miners :

[bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=168174.0)

And it gives you this two alternatives:

- Homebrew (Mac OS X): brew tap nwoolls/cryptocoin && brew install bfgminer
- Mac OS X: compile from source using Homebrew, or try MacMiner

Answer (score 0):

Alas, Kolivas and Kanoi (cgminer maintainers) don't actively support OSX, although it compiles and runs fairly problem-free on OSX.

Just to be clear, all your attempts to *download* cgminer have failed? That is, you are unable to get a running, compiled binary on to your computer? Or have you tried running, e.g. http://spaceman.ca/cgminer/ and it has failed to launch? Try the program provided by the link, and tell us how it goes.

Comment: What I meant was that all versions I had downloaded that were meant to work on my machine failed to compile. I have not seen the page you linked to, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Asteroid](http://www.asteroidapp.com/) - it's a graphical UI built on top of cgminer for OSX.

Comment: @cbbcbail any luck with Asteroid?